# Nextjs13 (App directory) deployment to Vercel. Not reading my API routes when making requests

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, next.js13

I have a problem with my vercel deployment. So to make things short, I can't do any requests to my API routes, because they are either responding with 404 ( with GET), or 405 with POST requests. It is important to note, that everything works perfectly fine in development.

This is my vercel.json config:

[image]

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I am connecting MongoDB via integrations correctly, `mongodb_uri` is present.
I also have any other needed env variables.

I have tried everything, and I am expecting to be able to do ANY requests to my API routes.

Comment: Add the API route code or ss that you are facing an issue.